# Show that if $P: H\rightarrow H$ is a projection, then $I-P$ is also a projection.

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to show that if $P: H\rightarrow H$ is a projection, then $I-P$ is also a projection.

Would it be enough to show that 
$$(I-P)(I-P) = I-PI-IP+PP = I-PI-IP+P=I-P-P+P=I-P ?$$
Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how you should do it. You could even combine one or two of these steps and simplify $IP$, $PI$ and $PP$ in one step rather than two.

Comment: That is good to hear! Thank you!

Comment: The expressions following the first and second = signs are the same, aren't they? Symbol for symbol the same. What is $-P+P=I-P?$ Why is that there?

Comment: Fixed the equality, they were the same indeed. Your second observation was merely a line break.

Comment: Btw, note that since $P(I-P)=0$, $(I-P)P=0$ and $\ker P \cap \ker (I-P) = 0$, the whole space $H$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{im} P \oplus \operatorname{im} (I-P)$, so $I-P$ serves as a projection on the complement.